# Explainable Boosting Machine Local and Global Explanation plots label size

Tags: visualization, plotting

I am using EBM for a research in python, the local and global explanation plots it produces come with preset font size, I want to change the resolution of the figure and the font size of labels and x and y ticks in the explanation plots. I am asking about the local and global explanation plots not the SHAP or LIME plots.

I have looked for it on the InterpretML github page and issues and scrolled through various webpages but haven't found anything helpful. Used gpt but it doesnot help either, it tries to use matplotlib but EBM plots are not compatible with it.

I have tried using matplotlib for the axis label resizing but it doesnot work with Explainable object. I have checked for solutions on stackoverflow and datascience stackexchange, but found one similar issue, that was using R not python. Please share any way it can be solved, because the plots labels are unreadable in the article if used as it is.

[image: The plot EBM is creating is attached.]